# Check post commit message to update staging and live server

Tags: svn, hook

We have a staging and live and we want to update a working copy of staging and live server based on the commit message sent by the author or the developer

Example

if we want to commit only in staging we will just commit the files and have a commit message like this "Change index.php code [staging]" and then the working copy on the staging folder or server will be updated if we do the commit message like this "Change index.php code [staging][live]" both staging and live server will then be updated.

This what I have done so far
on post_commit I add this line

```
svn update --quiet --trust-server-cert --non-interactive --username xxxxxx --password xxxxxx /var/www/staging
```

What we want to do in code is

```
if commit-message contains "[staging]"
    svn update --quiet --trust-server-cert --non-interactive --username xxxxxx --password xxxxxx /var/www/staging

if commit-message contains "[live]"
      svn update --quiet --trust-server-cert --non-interactive --username xxxxxx --password xxxxxx /var/www/live
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this possible?

Yes, this is possible. But you wanted to ask "How to do it?"

- Read about parameters of [post-commit hooks in SVN](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.reposhooks.post-commit.html)
- Read about [svnlook log](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svnlook.c.log.html)
- Read about [gawk](http://linux.die.net/man/1/grep) (plus, f.e., [15 Practical Grep Command Examples In Linux / UNIX](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/03/15-practical-unix-grep-command-examples/)) in case of *Nix OS (better case) - note `-q|-c` options, of [findstr](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/findstr.mspx?mfr=true) in case of Windows (worse case, but you can install and use [GOW](https://github.com/bmatzelle/gow/wiki) for getting `grep`)
- Discover [empty environment in hook scripts](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.reposadmin.create.html#svn.reposadmin.hooks.configuration)
- Combine new knowledge into some code, where core is

  svnlook log ... | grep -q ... && svn up...